# How do I change the color of text in Geom.label?

Tags: julia, gadfly

Can't find any options here http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/themes.html. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found it `point_label_color` here:

https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/theme.jl

Seems they haven't put it into the documents.